# SQL Server : reverse engineering view and stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reverse-engineering

I need some help from your side.

For example I have a SQL Server view `MyView`.

```
Adb.vs.MyView
```

with columns:

```
ID
Name
Address
Email
Phone
```

Logic behind the view is next

```
SELECT
    Ac.AccountID AS ID,
    Ac.AccountName AS Name,
    Ad.Main_Adress AS Address,
    Em.Main_Email AS Email,
    Concat(Ph.Phone_Area_Code,Ph.Mobile_Phone_Number) AS Phone  
FROM
    Bdb.dbo.Account AS Ac
INNER JOIN
    Cdb.dbo.Address AS Ad ON Ac.AccountID = Ad.AccountID
INNER JOIN
    Cdb.dbo.Emails AS Em ON Ac.AccountID = Em.AccountID
INNER JOIN
    Cdb.dbo.PhoneBook AS Ph ON Ac.AccountID = Ph.AccountID
```

**NOTE:**

No KEY relations build between all this tables.

My target to reverse engineer this view to get next kind of result:

[image: Desired Output]

Please suggest any kind of **tool/tools** or **scripts** to perform this.

Also, if somebody know similar solution but for Rev.En. stored procedures which was used to populating data into tables **I will be really appreciated**

bec. I will need to reverse tons of such kind views and stored procedures in nearest future.

Thanks in advance for any kind of support !

Comment: Not easily possible, as output columns of a view may not be directly related in source tables and columns. They may be the result of expressions that calculate based on the values of multiple columns in source tables, (or other views which get their input from other tables and views), or, for that matter, output may be constant expressions that are not dependent on any table field at all, or environmental data like current date time, etc.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the system views.  Most of what you want is probably available in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE.  For example:

```
USE Adb
GO

Select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE
where VIEW_NAME='MyView'
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Views are just stored SQL scripts that SQL Server adds into your query as a sub select.  Consequently the fields used are not actually saved within SQL Server in the same way that table definitions are.  Your best bet is to script out all your views using SQL Server Management Studio and plug the files into a tool such as the [General SQL Parser](http://www.sqlparser.com/) which can output the columns and tables that are used in that script.

It isn't perfect but should get you a long way towards what you are trying to achieve.  You can try it for free [here.](http://107.170.101.241:8080/getTableColumn/)